# Partially deduce arguments with constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Take the following class (C++17)

```cpp
#include <variant>
template <typename Error, typename T>
class Optional
{
public:
    constexpr Optional(T&& value)
    : m_variant(std::forward<T>(value))
    {}

private:
    std::variant<Error, T> m_variant = Error{};
};

template <typename E, typename T>
Optional<E, T> MakeOptional(T&& val) { return Optional<E, T>{val}; }

enum class Error
{
    ERROR,
    OTHER_ERROR,
};
```

The following compiles just fine

```cpp
Optional<Error, int> opt1{4};
auto opt3 = MakeOptional<Error>(7);
```

but this does not

```cpp
Optional<Error> opt2{4}; // does not compile "too few template arguments for class template 'Optional'"
```

Is it possible to make the code above compile? It should be able to deduce the second template argument with the constructor's parameter just like MakeOptional() does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) is a "all or nothing".

See the [note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Notes)

> Class template argument deduction is only performed if no template argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified, deduction does not take place.

Comment: Allowing that would have some pitfall: conversion `Foo<A> foo = Foo<A, B>();` would not be possible  (`foo` would be `Foo<A, B>`). CTAD is already *problematic* with copy constructor: `std::optional o(t)` when `t` is already an `optional` (so `std::make_*` are still useful).